# Vaadin 14 grid with checkboxes as rendered components

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

I created a grid that has four columns. The first column shows a name, the other three columns represent different roles. Each of those three columns is filled with check boxes in order to assign a specific role to a specific name.  That's as far as i have come so far.
In each column and in each row there should only be one selected checkbox allowed. So in total i do have exactly one selection per checkbox column. How do i implement this?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I realize I might have misunderstood the question entirely. If you want to have 3 columns, with each having multiple CheckBoxes where only 1 can be selected per column, then you should use a [RadioButtonGroup](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-radio-button/java-examples) in each column and bind each to a different Enum field of your griditem class.

---

Instead of showing how to do three columns with a CheckBox in each, while only one CheckBox can be selected, I will show **a different way** to achieve the same information about the item.

The reason for this is the solution that what you want to achieve is not easily doable, since each CheckBox is defined in a scope that does not know the other Checkboxes of the same item. Therefore you would need to implement your only-one-selected rule inside the itemclass' setters, which is not optimal. I mean, it is possible, but I'd rather change the structure to something more apt. Usually you don't want to put this kind of business logic into your bean classes.

---

How would I solve the problem at hand?
**Create a new Enum**, which will **replace all 3 boolean fields** in your item class. Now in your grid you will only need one column for a ComboBox to select the enum.
I chose an Enum because this matches your needs here perfectly. With an Enum, you may have several options, but you can select only one (or none).

To better show what I mean, let's use an example Class for the Grid items, `Foo`. Your version has 3 booleans which your three grid-CheckBoxes are bound to. Let's call them `isA`, `isB`, `isC`.

```
// your version of the griditem class
public class Foo {
    private boolean isA, isB, isC = false;

    // constructor, getters, setters 
}

// how the columns are added in the grid (approximately) (without editor):
Grid<Foo> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.addComponentColumn((item) -> {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.setValue(item.isA());
    checkBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> item.setA(event.getValue()); // inside setA() method you need to set isB and isC to false if the new value is true. No good!
    return checkBox;
});
grid.addComponentColumn((item) -> {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.setValue(item.isB());
    checkBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> item.setB(event.getValue()); // inside setB() method you need to set isB and isC to false if the new value is true. No good!
    return checkBox;
});
grid.addComponentColumn((item) -> {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.setValue(item.isC());
    checkBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> item.setC(event.getValue()); // inside setC() method you need to set isB and isA to false if the new value is true. No good!
    return checkBox;
});
```

And here is how it would look after my changes

```
public class Foo {
    private AbcEnum abcEnum = null;

    // constructor, getters, setters 
}

public Enum AbcEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C;
}

// how the columns are added (without editor):
Grid<Foo> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.addComponentColumn((item) -> {
    ComboBox<AbcEnum> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
    comboBox.setValue(item.getAbcEnum());
    comboBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> item.setAbcEnum(item.getValue()));
    return comboBox;
});
```

I wrote "without editor" in the comments about adding the column, because this code will add the ComboBox/CheckBox as clickable and functional components for each grid item, without needing to open the editor for an item to change the values. If you are indeed using an [editor](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/grid-editor), you can add these functional inputs as editorComponents (and bind them to the editor-binder instead of using setValue and addValueChangeListener), and show only the current value in the normal columns (not editable - therefore no inputs like CheckBox or ComboBox are required)